# is there any solution to duplicate plugin error

Tags: plugins, duplicates

[getting while creating a flutter project install plugin JetBrains later android studio stopped and later giving me duplicate plugin error .
my android studio is not opening but giving me an internal error.
[getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO1Cm.png)
even after reinstall the issue persists
what to do to solve this error
please help me
expecting to resolve this issue and want to work with my android studio again